# VBA Macro to copy result to other worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Let's say I define D1:D100 as "Projection". and this "Projection" will change depends on cell B2 (Age),B3 (Gender),B4 (Deposit).

And i need to Run 4 Scenarios.

1. Age : 40, Gender : Male, Deposit : 1000
2. Age : 30, Gender : Male, Deposit : 2000
3. Age : 40, Gender : Female, Deposit : 1500
4. Age : 30, Gender : Female, Deposit : 2500

And i have 4 Sheets ("40 M","30 M","40 F","30 F") to paste the Projection.

I want to create macro to Run this 4 Scenarios , and paste the Projection to each Sheet ( Scenario 1 to Sheet "40 M",Scenario 2 to Sheet "30 M" etc). Anyone can help?

Comment: you want to copy D1:D100 to sheet "40 M" after B2 is set to "40", B3 is "Male" and "B4" is set to "1000". then do this for the second example... hard coding this will take longer than recording the macro while doing this manually... have you tried that?

Comment: yeah I know, I already tried this manually, but the problem is I have some assumption that affect "Projection" (D1:D100), I keep changing that to see the impact. I already change the assumption like 8 times. I think if there is a way to create this macro, it would be better

Comment: have tried to record it?

Answer (score 0):

Copy projections to other sheets. In each sheet apply references to the first sheet where you have your variables and assumptions.